# Validate Data & insert data into mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am making a helpdesk page where i have page to raise a ticket. I have form where i want Issue Type & Query field to be filled mandatory & validate data for extension no. i.e it should be in no. only.
I have tried code to get it via ajax & form validation but not able to execute the code & values are not getting inserted into the mysql db.

Please Help !

Ticket.php

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Raise Ticket</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {   
            // Form validation.
            if ($('.validate-issue').val() === '') { $('.issue-error').fadeIn(); }   
            if ($('.validate-query').val() === '') { $('.query-error').fadeIn(); }   
            // Grab form values
            var formData = {
                    'ename'    : $('input[name=ename]').val(),
                    'date'     : $('input[name=date]').val(),   
                    'ext'  : $('input[name=ext]').val(),
                    'issue'    : $('select[name=issue]').val(),
                    'query'     : $('input[name=query]').val(),
                    'upload'       : $('input[name=upload]').val()
                    }; 
            if($('.validate-issue').val().trim()) &&($('.validate-query').val().trim()){
            // Ajax form submit.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "insertticket.php",
                data: formData,
                success: function()
                {
                alert('Ticket has been raised');
                }                   
            });
            } else { alert('Please enter the mandatory fields'); } });
            });
            </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading"><h1 align="center">Helpdesk-Support</h1></div>
<hr>
<div class="panel-body" align="center">
<h2>Raise Ticket!</h2>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="text">Name:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" disabled class="form-control" id="text" name="ename" value="<?php echo ucwords($_SESSION['usr_name']);  ?>">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="date">Date:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">          
        <input type="text"  class="form-control" disabled id="date" name="date" value="<?php date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta"); echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s')?>">
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="ext">Extension No.:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ext" name="ext" placeholder="Enter Extension No.">
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="issue">Issue Type:</label>    
<div class="col-sm-10">               
        <select class="form-control" id="validate-issue" name="issue"><span class="issue-error">Enter Issue Type</span>
    <option>Select an option</option>
    <option>Hardware Issue</option>
    <option>Network Issue</option>
    <option>Software Issue</option>
    <option>ERP</option>
    <option>CRM</option>
  </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="query">Query:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" id="validate-query" name="query" placeholder=" Enter Query here"></textarea><span class="query-error">Enter Detailed Query</span>
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="text">Upload File:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="filetoupload" name="upload" >
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="panel-footer" align="center">&copy Copyright <?php echo date("Y");?></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

insertticket.php

```
<?php 
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="helpdesk"; // Database name 

// Connect to server and select database.
$conn=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("cannot connect"); 

mysqli_select_db($conn,$db_name);


$emp_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ename']);
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['date']);
$issue_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['issue']);
$query = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['query']);
$ext_no. = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ext']);
$attachment = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['upload']);

$sqli="select * from user where name='$emp_name'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sqli);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$emp_code=$row['emp_code'];
$dept=$row['dept'];
$location=$row['location'];
$emailid=$row['emailid'];
$contact_no.=$row['contact_no.'];
}

$sql="INSERT INTO ticket (ticket_no.,emp_code,emp_name,dept,location,emailid,contact_no.,date,issue_type,query,ext_no.,attachment)
VALUES('','$emp_code','$emp_name','$dept','$location','$emailid','$contact_no.','$date','$issue_type','$query','$ext_no.','$attachment')";
if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
  {
echo "Record added";

  }
else
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
 }

?>
```

Comment: if you are a fresher try on your own first,do some google ...if not getting your ans then post...

Comment: Sir i tried this on my own & googled as well but still stuck on dis so i have posted it !

Comment: I don't know if mysql will support columns having period (.) just like what you have here
`$sql="INSERT INTO ticket (ticket_no.,emp_code,emp_name,dept,location,emailid,contact_no.,date,issue_type,query,ext_no.,attachment)
VALUES('','$emp_code','$emp_name','$dept','$location','$emailid','$contact_no.','$date','$issue_type','$query','$ext_no.','$attachment')";`
          
you might want to remove those dots?

Comment: Ok. Thank You! Checked that also but it's not able to insert data into the database

Comment: check this http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_required and for numeric check use isNAN() or html type="number" and main part is dont use dot(.) in column name.

Comment: Thank You Sir ! Will do the same & check

Comment: Please, for all that is holy, find the errors in the mySQL logs and append them to the question. You are wasting everyone's time without those logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your triggering your script on its first load only. You can try [`.submit()`](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) of jQuery.
- I'm not also certain if you can upload files just by getting its content by name/class/id.
- Isn't [`.trim()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) just for removing extra spaces, and not for checking content?
- What is up with those dots(`.`) in your column names anyway?
- You should use `$_FILES["upload"]["name"]` instead of `$_POST["upload"]` for getting the file name attached by the user
- Where is your code for uploading the file?

You can try `required` attribute of HTML for the meantime:

```
<input required="true" type="text" disabled class="form-control" id="text" name="ename" value="<?php echo ucwords($_SESSION['usr_name']);  ?>">
```

And why don't we try `.submit()` in your case:

First, we have to give a unique data attribute for your `<form>` by adding an `id` attribute.

```
<form id="form-submission" class="form-horizontal" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

Then for your script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("form#form-submission").submit(function(){ /* WHEN THE FORM IS SUBMITTED */

    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]); /* ALL THE DATA IS IN HERE INCLUDING THE FILE ATTACHED */

    $.ajax({ /* CALL AJAX */
      url: "insertticket.php", /* THE FILE WHERE THE DATA WILL GO */
      type: "POST", /* TYPE OF METHOD TO BE USED TO PROCESS THE DATA */
      data: formData, /* THE DATA TO BE PROCESSED */
      contentType: false, /* TYPE OF DATA TO BE PASSED; FOR FILE PURPOSES THAT IS WHY IT IS SET TO FALSE */
      processData: false, /* PREVENT AUTOMATIC PROCESSING */
      success: function(result){ /* IF DATA IS PROCESSED SUCCESSFULLY */
        alert(result); /* ALERT THE RETURNED DATA FROM inserticket.php */
      }
    });

    return false;

  });

});
```

You're also already using [`mysqli_`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), so its easier to convert your code to [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead.

This is your insertticket.php:

```
<?php

  $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "helpdesk");

  /* CHECK CONNECTION */
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
  }

  if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT emp_code, dept, location, emailid, contact_no FROM user WHERE name = ?")){ /* PREPARE YOUR QUERY */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST["ename"]); /* BIND THIS DATA TO YOUR QUERY, REPLACING ? WITH $_POST["ename"]; s STANDS FOR STRING TYPE */
    $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE QUERY */
    $stmt->bind_result($emp_code, $dept, $location, $emailid, $contact_no); /* BIND THE RESULTS TO THESE VARIABLES CORRESPONDINGLY */
    $stmt->fetch(); /* FETCH THE RESULT */
    $stmt->close(); /* CLOSE THE PREPARED STATEMENT */
  }

  if($stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO ticket (emp_code, emp_name, dept, location, emailid, contact_no, date, issue_type, query, ext_no, attachment) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")){
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssssssss", $emp_code, $_POST["ename"], $dept, $location, $emailid, $contact_no, $_POST["date"], $_POST["issue"], $_POST["query"], $_POST["ext"], $_FILES["upload"]["name"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    echo 'Record added';
  }

  move_upload_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], "/system/uploads/".$_FILES["upload"]["name"]); /* UPLOAD THE FILE TO /system/uploads/ FOLDER; JUST REPLACE YOUR DESIRED DIRECTORY */

?>
```

- Always take a look at your browser's console log for errors
- You should also consider renaming the uploaded file by the user through your code so that it will be unique inside your folder and database. To prevent duplicate file name that would lead to overwriting of files

Comment: Thank You ! Working for the same